# PyQT5, QToolbar, Qaction. Как сделать смену иконки при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

В окне программы имеется панель инструментов `QToolbar` с кнопками `QAction`. Работают в режиме обычных кнопок, НЕ вкл/выкл `action.setCheckable(False)`.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли и как сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку иконка менялась на другую, а при отпускании восстанавливалась по умолчанию? По аналогии с `press / release`.

В режиме выключателя `action.setCheckable(True)` это реализуется прописыванием иконок:

```
icon.addFile("my_icon_off.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
icon.addFile("my_icon_on.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
```

А вот как сделать подобное в режиме кнопки - не могу сообразить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAction не имеет соответствующих сигналов, но вы можете добавить на тулбар кнопку, у которой такие возможности есть:

```
button = QPushButton('test');
button.setIcon(QIcon('my_icon_off.png'));
button.pressed.connect(lambda: button.setIcon(QIcon('my_icon_on.png')));
button.released.connect(lambda: button.setIcon(QIcon('my_icon_off.png')));
self.toolbar.addWidget(button);
```

Comment: Да, это действительно единственный верный вариант. Никакие другие костыльные уловки с QAction не прокатили. Даже переопределение класса с наследованием QWidget не помогло))
Спасибо!